# Angular loop through all the objects inside $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have a requirement where I need to loop through $scope and inside $scope loop through all the objects, arrays and print there key value pair, I would not know beforehand the name of each object or array in scope. for eg: scope may have following objects, there may be other objects/arrays and I would not know the name of them

```
$scope.person = [{
    fname: "Jim",
    lname: ""
},
{fname: "Tim",
    lname: "Tom"}
];

 $scope.job = { title: {subTitle: "developer", name: "john"}, company: {name: "xyz"}

};
```

Now, I want to loop through $scope and print

fname: "Jim"
lname: ""
fname: "Tim"
lname: "Tom"
subTitle: "developer"
name: "john"
name: "xyz"

Comment: What is use case for ever needing to loop through all of `$scope`? Sounds like you should be setting an additional property of `$scope` also to store all the data models and then you won't have to check if a scope property is a function also

Comment: I can't think of a usecase where this makes sense. Maybe create an object where you store your needed data `$scope.data = {}` and save everything in there.

Comment: Or do you just want to see all your Scope Properties ?

Comment: I have few pages and each page will have some specific properties but under a different hierarchy and I want a generic way to loop through the scope and access those properties. For e.g. each page may have a property fname but it may be under person object on one page but may be under different object in another page and in different hierarchy like under an object which itself is part of another object.

Comment: I think thats more a javaScript Problem than AngularJs - or perhaps you should think one more time for a better solution on your problem you try to solve.